# How imagenet mean and std derived?

Tags: image-preprocessing, fastai

To use pre-trained models it is a preferred practice to normalize the input images with imagenet standards.

`mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406]` and `std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]`.

How are these parameters derived?

Answer (score 1):

> These are calculated based on millions of images of ImageNet.

[Ref - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151507/why-pytorch-officially-use-mean-0-485-0-456-0-406-and-std-0-229-0-224-0-2)

[Ref - MachinelearningMastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-manually-scale-image-pixel-data-for-deep-learning/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Pytorch's [docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html), you can calculate `mean` and `std` using this:

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms as T

transform = T.Compose([T.Resize(256), T.CenterCrop(224), T.ToTensor()])
dataset = datasets.ImageNet(".", split="train", transform=transform)

means = []
stds = []
for img in subset(dataset):
    means.append(torch.mean(img))
    stds.append(torch.std(img))

mean = torch.mean(torch.tensor(means))
std = torch.mean(torch.tensor(stds))
```